# Apple O-Match Linker error when trying to use Fast Corner Detector Success Labs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compiler-errors

i am trying to implement this: http://www.hatzlaha.co.il/150842/FAST-Corner-V2 in my app. They share complete compiling project that is doing what I want. I am trying to use it in my app but I got stuck in compiling my application after copying function.

I got this error from compiler:

```
Ld /Users/wojciechradomski2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARmgr-bxkvnxdnsjbaioahqhygfsmofpxn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARmgr.app/ARmgr normal armv6
    cd /Users/wojciechradomski2/Documents/xCode/AR/ARmgr
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -L/Users/wojciechradomski2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARmgr-bxkvnxdnsjbaioahqhygfsmofpxn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/wojciechradomski2/Documents/xCode/AR/ARmgr/ARmgr/opencv_device/lib -F/Users/wojciechradomski2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARmgr-bxkvnxdnsjbaioahqhygfsmofpxn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/wojciechradomski2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARmgr-bxkvnxdnsjbaioahqhygfsmofpxn/Build/Intermediates/ARmgr.build/Debug-iphoneos/ARmgr.build/Objects-normal/armv6/ARmgr.LinkFileList -dead_strip -lstdc++ -lz -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -framework OpenGLES -framework AssetsLibrary -framework MobileCoreServices -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreMedia -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lcv -lcxcore -o /Users/wojciechradomski2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ARmgr-bxkvnxdnsjbaioahqhygfsmofpxn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARmgr.app/ARmgr

Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "fast9_detect_nonmax(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int, int*)", referenced from:
      -[CameraViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in CameraViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As readme file says I need only to import fast.h, and I am doing it.
I checked all libraries, imports and frameworks - I have them all.

The above error displays even with someting like this:

```
fast9_score(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

After removing this line everything compiles fine.

Any ideas what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You are providing very little information. Have you added the sources for this library to your project/target? Are those sources compiling as well?

Comment: I don't know what to add more. I have file fast.h and fast_9.c I have both of them in my project. If I go to target compile sources I also have this fast_9.c file there.

Comment: When you say you import it, do you mean as the header file in the actual file where you call fast9_score, or into the project as a whole? Make sure you do both. Is there any chance that the fast.h implements something that you are missing? Also, if you added the file to you project did you make sure that you told XCode to make a copy and put it in the project group folder?

Comment: I have header file as #import and I also have this file in my source tree. I do have all files copied into my project folder as well. fast.h file has metods that i have got in other .c files implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my cursory glance, the missing function is defined in fast.cc. So make sure you have it in your project, and it gets compiled and linked with your desired target.

**Edit**: A hint: if you get missing symbols in the linker, just grep for the files which contain that symbol. You may find the one that defines it... I just did a "grep -r fast9_detect_nonmax *" in the source directory of the project you linked in your post, and found the file.

Comment: well it wasn't exactly this problem (i got all files already in project), but thanks to your post i found solution. I had all library files added with .c extension. After changing all files to .cc extension project compiles fine.